# feedback BJT ac analysis

Tags: ac, bjt, homework, analysis

I'm having trouble with a BJT question. How can we do ac analysis of this circuit?

[image: Question circuit]

My attempted solution is this:

[image: Attempted solution]

Comment: You need to show some effort before other people will want to try to help you.. what have you tried yourself so far?

Comment: Sorry sir, I'm new here.Actually, I have a solution I made. But i can't be sure.
Can you help me if i show?

Comment: You can simulate it. You can also draw an equivalent pi-circuit, come up with some transfer function. Also, yes, go right ahead and post your solution by editing your question.

Comment: The DC operating point of that circuit is highly \$\beta\$-dependent. Which means the value of \$r_e\$, an important AC analysis element, is also very much at question. Odds are, the circuit is saturated. If you assume it is, then \$I_\text{C}\approx 2.45\:\text{mA}\$ and \$I_\text{B}\approx 63.5\:\mu\text{A}\$. This means \$\beta\approx 39\$. And that probably confirms the prior assumption that it was in saturation. So you can't really analyze it as an active-mode BJT. Unless this is an unusual BJT. If it is in active mode, then \$r_e\$ is unknowable.

Answer (score 1):

Without R3, that circuit would be guaranteed to self-servo (self-regulate) into a non-saturated mode of biasing, with a linear operating point. Particularly if the ratio of Rbase to Rcollector were about 100 (many transistors have beta near 100), you'd have a bias_point of VDD/2 which permits maximum +- voltage swings on the collector.

BUT

With R3, its hard to say that circuit is in linear (non_sat) biasing.

If the transistor has very high beta, then R1 (50Kohm) needs little voltage across it to provide adequate base current, and the junction of the two collector resistors needs to be near the collector voltage or the devices enters saturation.

Answer (score 0):

**DC Operating Point:**
The transistor will be in active mode if collector-base junction is reverse biased. Assuming voltage \$V_1\$ at \$R_2\$, \$R_3\$ junction.
$$V_B = V_1 - I_BR_1$$
$$V_C = V_1 - \beta I_BR_3$$
$$\implies V_{BC} = I_B(\beta R_3 - R_1) < 0 \implies \beta < \frac{R_1}{R_3} \approx 33$$
Thus, if the current gain of the transistors is less than 33, the transistors can be in active mode.

**Small Signal Gain:**
It seems like the circuit should be driven by a current source since its input impedance is small. For a current source input drive, I think, the easiest way to solve the circuit is by finding its Loop-Gain.
Using Middlebrook's Formula, it is known that:
$$\frac{1}{L_T} = \frac{1}{L_i}+  \frac{1}{L_v}$$
Here, \$L_v\$ is the loop gain with applying input voltage at one end of the broken loop with other end open circuit and \$L_i\$ is the loop gain with with input current at one end of the broken loop and short circuit at the other end.

Turn off all the independent sources, and break the loop at the input of the BJT. Then,
$$L_v = g_mR_2$$
$$L_i = \beta(\frac{R_2}{R_2+R_1})$$
$$L_T = \frac{\beta g_mR_2}{g_m(R_1+R_2)+\beta}$$
The forward transfer function is:
$$A = \beta(R_2+R_3)$$
The total gain would be then:
$$G = \frac{A}{1+L_T}$$
This can be easily calculated now.

Comment: What are zi and zo values ?

Comment: Which zi and zo values are you asking about?

Comment: sir is the solution i made right? If not, how should the drawing of the circuit be?